# Filtering xml using Powershell Where-Object

Tags: xml, powershell

Assignment is to read the following xml code back into Powershell and only show items with an attribute: event="1".

```
xml file created by Powershell script createsim.ps1
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<simulation name="Protocal Simulation">
  <duration type="clock">100000</duration>
  <density>1.1</density>
  <ideal_degree>12</ideal_degree>
  <radius>86</radius>
  <supportedchannels>[1,4,7,9,11,13]</supportedchannels>
  <class>Field.RandomField</class>
  <width>1000</width>
  <height>1000</height>
  <description event="1">Re-form the network</description>
  <action event="1">densityChangeDetected()</action>
  <description event="2">End the simulation</description>
  <action event="2">end()</action>
</simulation>"
```

Piping output of script and exporting object.

```
PS C:\scripts> C:\scripts\createsim.ps1 | Export-Clixml C:\scripts\simtemp.xml
```

Importing object.

```
PS C:\scripts> $simxml = Import-Clixml C:\scripts\simtemp.xml
```

Looking for event attribute.

```
PS C:\scripts> $xmlout = $simxml | Where-Object ($_.event -eq 1) | Sort-Object event

PS C:\scripts> $xmlout

PS C:\scripts> write-host $xmlout
```

No error messages and nothing prints out.

I would appreciate any help or hints. I am using Powershell 4.0 on Windows 8.1

Comment: Are you sure you are using PowerShell 2.0 on Windows 8.1 ?

Comment: Sorry it is version 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I follow why the `Export-Clixml` is necessary. If `createsim.ps1` generates XML, you can just use that XML directly without the export and import. Then your job becomes much easier. Assuming your script generates the XML noted in your post, this code:

```
   > $xml = [XML](Get-Content C:\scripts\createsim.ps1)
   > foreach ($node in $xml.simulation.ChildNodes)
     {
        if ($node.event -eq 1) { $node.OuterXml }
     }
```

gives you:

```
   <description event="1">Re-form the network</description>
   <action event="1">densityChangeDetected()</action>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. When I run your code I get this error.Cannot convert value "System.Object[]" to type "System.Xml.XmlDocument". Error: "The specified node cannot be 
inserted as the valid child of this node, because the specified node is the wrong type."
At C:\scripts\event.ps1:1 char:1
+ $xml = [XML](C:\scripts\createsim.ps1)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastToXmlDocument

Comment: Thanks for the hint djs! After I tweaked your code I got it to work using:                                                              PS C:\scripts> [XML]$xml = Get-Content C:\scripts\simulation.xml
               foreach ($node in $xml.simulation.ChildNodes)
               {
                  if ($node.event -eq 1) { $node.OuterXml }
               }
<description event="1">Re-form the network</description>
<action event="1">densityChangeDetected()</action>

Comment: +1 it works adding `Get-content` I add a solution with `select-xml`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try @djs solution using :

```
$xml = [XML](Get-Content(C:\scripts\createsim.ps1))
```

You can Select-Xml CmdLet try :

```
Select-Xml -Path "C:\temp\test.xml" -XPath "/simulation/action[@event]" | % {$_.node}
```

or

```
Select-Xml -Path "C:\temp\test.xml" -XPath "/simulation/action" | where {$_.node.event -eq '1'} | % {$_.Node.OuterXml}
```

For the same result as @djs :

```
Select-Xml -Path "C:\temp\test.xml" -XPath "/simulation/*[@event]" | where {$_.node.event -eq '1'} | % {$_.Node.OuterXml}
```

Comment: Thank you JPBlanc for your help I appreciate you taking the time to help me.